# Shortcut to change keyboard layout in Linux Mint (Cinnamon)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I would like to have a keyboard shortcut that goes to the next keyboard layout I have "saved". Like <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in Microsoft Windows and Gnome.

Answer (score 49):

This was a pain to find, but if you left-click the system icon, then choose "keyboard settings" and then "Layouts", there is an "Options..." button.  Click that, then a popup will show where you can scroll down to set the shortcut to just about anything:

[image: keyboard options popup]

Answer (score 8):

Yesterday I upgraded to **Linux Mint 20** from **Linux Mint 18.3**. After then I spent a couple of hours finding the keyboard shortcut to change the **keyboard layout**.

Here are the screenshots of steps to enable the preferred shortcut key to change the **keyboard layout** in **Linux Mint 20**:

Step 1: Right-click on the language flag in the **Panel** and click the **Keyboard Settings**.

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the **option button** under **Layouts** tab.

[image]

**Step 3:** Choose your preferred layout under Switch to another layout section.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut is shift + capslock in mint 19.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but when you open Keyboard layouts, there are shortcuts for switching between them. Default alternative shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+K.

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you don't like any of the shortcuts on the list then you can do the following:

1. **Install [xkb-switch](https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch):**
2. Install the dependencies:

- `sudo apt install libxkbfile-dev`
- `sudo apt install cmake`
- `sudo apt install g++`
- `sudo apt install git`

1. Clone the repository:

- `git clone https://github.com/grwlf/xkb-switch xkb-switch-master`
- `cd xkb-switch-master/`

1. Build and install:

- `mkdir build && cd build`
- `cmake ..`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

1. Update the program cache

- `sudo ldconfig`

1. Test it's working

- Running `xkb-switch -p` should display `gb` (or whatever your current layout is)

1. **Set up your desired keyboard shortcut**
2. Navigate to keyboard settings (System Settings -> Keyboard)
3. Switch to the "Shortcuts" tab and select "Custom Shortcuts" under "Categories"
4. Press "Add custom shortcut", and set the command to `xkb-switch -n`
5. Set the shortcut you want using the "Keyboard bindings" section (I use `Crl+Alt+K`)
6. **Test the shortcut to make sure it's working!**

---

Hope this helps someone, it took me ages to find this solution.